# Touchpad click not working on ASUS TUF F15 FX507ZE (2022 edition)

Tags: touchpad

I have problem with my laptop. The touch-pad mostly works - even mutlitouch gestures but no reaction on clicks.
I've always have this issue since Ubuntu 21.10. Now I have 23.04.

Kernel:

```
Linux tuf 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  6 07:48:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
  *-input:11
       product: ASUF1204:00 2808:0104 Mouse
       physical id: d
       logical name: input30
       logical name: /dev/input/event12
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
       capabilities: i2c
  *-input:12
       product: ASUF1204:00 2808:0104 Touchpad
       physical id: e
       logical name: input31
       logical name: /dev/input/event13
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
       capabilities: i2c
```